# Cabal install uses old versioned binary

Tags: haskell, cabal

I downloaded haskell shell package - `HSH` from [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HSH) - with version 2.1.2. Then i unzipped it, and did `cd HSH-2.1.2 && cabal configure && cabal build && cabal install`.
On `cabal install`, it threw the error,

```
setup-Simple-Cabal-1.18.1.5-x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.4: 
dist/package.conf.inplace:
inappropriate type

cabal --version
```

shows,

```
cabal-install version 1.22.0.0
```

So, why does `cabal install` use 1.18 instead of 1.22.

I ran all commands in non-sudo mode.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Note that the correct continuation to `cabal configure && cabal build` is not `cabal install` but `cabal copy && cabal register`. Or you may replace all four steps by the single `cabal install`.

Comment: On the topic of your problem description: I don't believe this is the full output of either the compilation error *or* the cabal versioning information. It may also be useful to include the output of `ghc-pkg list Cabal`.

Comment: @jww : cabal is the tool for downloading and installing Haskell libraries, why would that be off-topic for S.O?

Comment: `ghc-pkg list Cabal` produces `WARNING: there are broken packages.  Run 'ghc-pkg check' for more details.
/opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4/package.conf.d
   Cabal-1.18.1.5
/home/sk/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.8.4/package.conf.d
`. But, when i do, `which cabal`, it just shows `/opt/cabal/1.22/bin/cabal`.

Comment: I have put a possible explanation for this problem on [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29837198/791604).